# Get the highest NSNumber in an NSSet

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsnumber, nsset

I have a `NSMutableSet` containing `NSNumber`s, I need to get the highest one. How would I do that?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `[mutableSet  valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self"]`.

Comment: This works, but you don't have to convert to an array first, you can apply `valueForKeyPath` directly to the set.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand.
I have for example a variable 
`NSMutableSet *set;`
Inside, I can have only numbers from 1 to 5.
My set contains now number 2 and 4.

I need to get the number 4.
If I want that I just need to write :
`[set valueForKeyPath:5];` ???
It will return automatically the number 4?

Thanks

Comment: @manonthemoon: You have to write it verbatim as in this answer. (There was a syntax error which I have fixed.)

Comment: @manonthemoon, you can copy paste the code replacing the set object it will work as is.This is the power of KVC. If you want to know more about KVC look at the developer reference,http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html